# Why do I sometimes get `lock': deadlock detected (fatal) error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deadlock, bitbucket

Some strange things are happening these days.

Sometimes while pushing to heroku I get the following errors:

```
<internal:prelude>:8:in `lock': deadlock detected (fatal)  

from <internal:prelude>:8:in `synchronize'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/vendor/lpxc.rb:57:in `puts'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:10:in `bench_msg'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:23:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:39:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:261:in `install_ruby'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:87:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:41:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block in instrument'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:39:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:84:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:48:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:41:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block in instrument'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:39:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:46:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:41:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block in instrument'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:39:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:36:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:12:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:113:in `log'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:11:in `block in <main>'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:36:in `call'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:36:in `block in trace'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:41:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block in instrument'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:36:in `trace'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:9:in `<main>'



!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

But if I push again after this a couple of times all works fine. What is happening?
Sometimes I even get that

> fatal:looseobjecta35c1489005cca1ffeb3c2d3e4d63988408b6a24(storedin.git/objects/a3/5c1489005cca1ffeb3c2d3e4d63988408b6a24) is corrupted

Why is this Happening?

Comment: To me those are git errors.

Comment: How to fix those or can we fix those?

Comment: I'm too experiencing the same problems recently. can anyone tell a solution.

Comment: The second error is definitely a git one, so I have no idea what to do about it. In the first - I guess you use some build tool which I don't know and you don't even provide a name of it, so… sorry, I cannot help.

Comment: I'm using OS X Mountaion lion. and I don't know about the build tool. How do I find that?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and I tried a second time and it worked.  It looks like some sort of Heroku glitch.

Comment: same here, ran for the second time